# How to install jdk6, apache-maven-3.0.3, ansible and Visual Studio 2005 on windows10

Tags: windows-10

I have requirement to install above packages on windows10 machine i.e VM using packer where either I call powershell or install it from choclatey.
I am not able to find this packages and even dont know how to install above requirement in powershell.
Can somebody please help on this?

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is not a PowerShell code question, so, this one is really off topic for this Q&A section. This is more a superuser or stackexchange thing.

Anyway, since you are here, if you have not have PowerShellGet (part of v5x and there is a download for [PowerShell v3x-4x](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49186)), nuget or chocolatey installed, then do so of course

Also, going directly to the chocolatey site, there is no jdk6 in the repo.

> There was no JDK6 package is in the repo
>
> https://chocolatey.org/packages?q=jdk

V8 is there and the below...

> Maven 3.6.0 https://chocolatey.org/search?q=apache+maven
>
> ansible https://chocolatey.org/packages?q=ansible
>
> Visual Studio 2005
>
> https://chocolatey.org/packages?q=visual+studio+2005

.. So you should be able to install them. That VS2K5 is not full Visual Studio of course (just the redistribute runtime stuff) as you'd have to buy that from Microsoft, and that isn't for sale any longer from them.

For legacy JDK, you are going to have to hit the Oracle (Java.com) site and even it says.

> Java SE 7, and Java SE 6 updates
>
> Updates for Java SE 7 released after
>   April 2015, and updates for Java SE 6 released after April 2013 are
>   only available to Oracle Customers through My Oracle Support (requires
>   support login).
>
> Java SE Subscription offers users commercial features, access to
>   critical bug fixes, security fixes, and general maintenance.
>
> https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index-jsp-138363.html#javasejdk